# Set database to open in non-exclusive mode

Tags: ms-access

I know that it is possible to copy a form from one Access project and paste it to another but when I try to do this, I get a message.

```
Could not use 'path_of_Access_file'; file already in use
```

I know that I need to open the file that I am copying in from in "shared" mode.  Where is the setting to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open the Options screen from the File menu.
2. Select Client Settings.
3. Scroll down to the Advanced menu and set the Default open mode.
4. Close and reopen the database

[image: Access Options]